# Orbeon Documentation for oxf.xforms.format.input.time

Tags: orbeon

```
<!-- [h]:[m]:[s] [P,*-2] or [h]:[m]:[s] [P,2-2] or [H]:[m]:[s] -->
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.xforms.format.input.time"                           value="[h]:[m]:[s] [P,*-2]"/>
```

I wonder if the Orbeon time picker can display hours with preceding zero e.g. parse from 5:00pm becomes 05:00pm, and found above properties.

Also, can anyone explain what `[P, *-2]` and `[P,2-2]` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your questions:

- You can use `[P,2-2]` if you don't want dots in *am* and *pm*.
- Adding leading zeros currently isn't supported. (If your organization has a PE or Dev Support subscription, you can contact Orbeon to see if this can be implemented as a "sponsored feature".)

And you can find more about the supported format in the section of the documentation about [`xf:input` formatting](http://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/xforms.html#for-xfinput).